# Add multiple events in Google Calendar using batch request

Tags: go, google-calendar-api, google-api-go-client

I want to add multiple events in google calendar using google calendar API. I am thinking of using batch request for the same but unfortunately, I couldn't find any helpful pkg or article to help me send batch request using golang.

can anyone please explain me how to send batch request to google calendar to insert event using golang.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to consider is why you want to bother with [batching](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/batch)

Batching is not going to save you quota, in some case it will increase the likly hood that you will get a flooding error.  All batching saves you is the number of HTTP calls.

You're limited to 50 calls in a single batch request and they must all be to the same authorized user.   So unless you are planning on inserting a large number of events to a single users calendar there is really no reason to work out batching.

That being said from what i can see the [google-apis-go-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/29) does not support batching and they dont intend to add it.  Which would mean that if you do in fact want to add batching you will need to check the first link i posted and code this manually yourself.

Comment: Thank you @DalmTo, I need to add request to the same authorized user.'

Comment: @DalmTo,  According to your experience would you please suggest, if I should use batching or not?

Comment: I have been working with these apis for more then 12 years.   I have done batching once and regretted.   I wouldn't bother.    Getting a working sample for calendar with go without batching shouldnt take to long.  Adding batching is going to take a while.