# List multiple user's calendar events using a batch request with google calendar API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to get public event details from multiple users in a batch request.

I can get 1 user's public event details by making a call to  https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/user@example.com/events.

But I can't find any documentation on a Calendar API batch request so I can do this for multiple users at one time.

Comment: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74568452/add-multiple-events-in-google-calendar-using-batch-request) which also tackles accessing events through batch requests on Google Calendar API. Does this answer your question, or at least provides information regarding it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your goal can be achieved by the batch requests. About `But I can't find any documentation on a Calendar API batch request so I can do this for multiple users at one time.`, unfortunately, now, I couldn't find the official document of the batch requests for Calendar API. The old URL of the official document of the batch request of Calendar API was `https://developers.google.com/calendar/batch`. But, unfortunately, in the current stage, it seems that this URL is linked to `https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html`.

But, I think that the basic structure of the request body for the batch requests is the same as that of the Drive API. [Ref1](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/performance#batch-requests) [Ref2 (Author: me)](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/efficient-file-management-using-batch-requests-google-apps-script) Actually, when I tested a sample script for retrieving the event lists from multiple calendars using the same structure for Drive API, I confirmed that the event lists are retrieved from each calendar.
It seems that the difference between Drive API and Calendar API is the batch path and the endpoint.

From your question, I guessed that you don't want a sample script and you want to know whether the event lists can be retrieved from multiple calendars using the batch requests because of no tags related to a specific language.

The simple sample request body of the batch requests for retrieving the event list from multiple calendars is as follows. In this case, the event list is retrieved from 2 calendars.

```
--sampleBoundary12345
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 1

GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId1}/events

--sampleBoundary12345
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: 2

GET https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{calendarId2}/events

--sampleBoundary12345--
```

When this request body is requested, the following sample result is returned.

```
--batch_###
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Origin
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer

{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"###\"",
 "summary": "###",
 "description": "###",
 "updated": "###",
 "timeZone": "###",
 "accessRole": "writer",
 "defaultReminders": [],
 "nextPageToken": "###",
 "items": [,,,]
}

--batch_###
Content-Type: application/http
Content-ID: response-2

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Origin
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer

{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"###\"",
 "summary": "###",
 "description": "###",
 "updated": "###",
 "timeZone": "###",
 "accessRole": "writer",
 "defaultReminders": [],
 "nextPageToken": "###",
 "items": [,,,]
}

--batch_###--
```

The raw response value is a string value as shown in the above value. So, if you want to retrieve the event items, it is required to parse it.

#### Note:

- In this case, as a requirement presupposition, you are required to have permission to read the event items from all calendars. Please be careful about this.
- As one important point, when you want to retrieve the event items from a calendar, even when `maxResults=2500` is used, only the 2500 items are retrieved. If you want to retrieve more event items, it is required to retrieve the next page using `pageToken`. Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, please be careful about this.
- From your tag of other questions, if you want to use Google Apps Script, this Google Apps Script library might be able to be used. [Ref (Author: me)](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest)
- From `I need to do this in Google Apps Script. Let me see if I can use what you shared to make this work.` in OP's reply comment, the sample script using [my library](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest) is as follows. You can see how to install the library at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/BatchRequest#how-to-install). And, please enable Calendar API at Advanced Google services.

  ```js
  function sample() {
    // Please set your calendar IDs.
    const calendarIds = ["### calendar ID 1 ###","### calendar ID 2 ###","### calendar ID 3 ###",,,];

    const requests = calendarIds.map(id => ({
      method: "GET",
      endpoint: `https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/${id}/events`
    }));
    const result = BatchRequest.EDo({ batchPath: "batch/calendar/v3", requests });
    console.log(result);
  }
  ```

  - This is a simple sample script. Please modify this to your actual situation.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan As additional information, in this case, the batch path is `batch/calendar/v3`. So, the endpoint of this request is `https://www.googleapis.com/batch/calendar/v3`.

Comment: I need to do this in Google Apps Script. Let me see if I can use what you shared to make this work.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Thank you for replying. About `I need to do this in Google Apps Script. Let me see if I can use what you shared to make this work.`, I added a sample script in my answer. Please confirm it.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I answered your additional request of `I need to do this in Google Apps Script. Let me see if I can use what you shared to make this work.`. After this, is there anything I can do? If your issue was not resolved by my answers, I have to apologize.

Comment: Hi. I'm on holiday so I haven't had time to check. I will check and confirm as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Thank you for replying. I understood `Hi. I'm on holiday so I haven't had time to check. I will check and confirm as soon as I get a chance.`.