api call fetch multiple calendars of same email with google api calendar
is there a way to in only one api call fetch events from 2 calendars of the same email
like:
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/Calendar1,CalendarId2
is it possible?

Based on the following posts: Can we get events for multiple calendar id's using Google Calendar API? and Can I use multiple calendarID's with the google calendar api?, you can only fetch events from one calendar at a time.

If my understanding of your question is correct, I guessed that this thread might be related to your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/77457373

This question is similar to: Can I use multiple calendarID's with the google calendar api?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
